# Selecting TD inside a table

Tags: jquery, html-table, selection

In jQuery, how to select ALL the TR that only has 2 TD inside?
Here's the sample:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>          
   <tr> /* I only want to select this. */
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mean "at least 2 `<td>`" or "exactly 2 `<td>`"?

Comment: why not use something a little faster like classes in your table to identify what you might need? (i'm assuming you generate the data of course)

Comment: @Jakub: Perhaps Eron doesn't control over how the HTML is generated, perhaps it is coming from a third party library (client-side or server-side), an external web service, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to reduce the `tr` to only those whose children count is 2

```
$('table tr').filter(function(){
    return $(this).children().length === 2;
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/xTNcG/

Answer (score 2):

***For at least two***

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(2)').parent();
```

- If there's a `td:nth-child(2)`, then obviously there's at least two `td`s

---

***For exactly two***

```
$('tr > td:nth-child(2):last-child').parent();
```

- If there's a `tr > td:nth-child(2):last-child`, then the second `td` is also the last `td`, so there must be only two.

Or like this:

```
$('tr').has('td:nth-child(2)');  // at least two

$('tr').has('td:nth-child(2):last-child');  // exactly two
```

Comment: I'm glad you're not a 10K user - if you were, you'd be able to see my stupid answer - let's just say eq didn't do what I assumed it did :-/  Fortunately I deleted it pretty quickly

Comment: @AdamRackis: Yeah, I've got a number of those out there.

Answer (score 0):

Use the length command. I came up with this, you might need to make some slight modifications.

```
$("table").find("tr").each(function() {
    len = $(this).find("td").length;
    if(len == 2) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/length/

Comment: I think you meant `$(this).find("td").length`

Comment: I did. Thanks for the heads up :)